# Auth declaration in kernal and routing in laravel not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-middleware

I had used JWT middleware for my one of the application.
My code is worked after some research but I have not understood the actual reason behind that.

I had introduced auth in kernel.php below is my code.

```
namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ....
    ....
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ....
        'jwt-auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\jwtMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

i am using **'jwt-auth'** as the jwt middleware.

but when using in routing. tried to use like **jwt-auth** but It will not work. then after some research used **jwt.auth** then working correctly. so why it's used by the **.** not **-**. logically we make auth with name **jwt-auth**.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth','api-header']], function () {

    // all routes to protected resources are registered here  
    Route::get('users/list', function(){
        $users = App\User::all();

        $response = ['success'=>true, 'data'=>$users];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    });
});
```

The same thing I was used for different middleware for including API header with **-** but it will work same as the kernel alias.

Comment: If your Model extends `Authenticatable` you can simply use the 'auth' middleware, this is one of the issues I had with `tymon/jwt-auth`. I found auth was what worked for me.

Comment: To let you know why `jwt-auth` is not working you would have to post the code for that file located `\App\Http\Middleware\jwtMiddleware`.

Comment: I already did it. but my question is that it will be not working with jwt-auth. it will be working if i am using jwt.auth

Comment: So what was the difference between that jwt-auth and jwt.auth.

Comment: You tell me, you create `jwt-auth` as your own middleware. How am I supposed to know what's in it? You haven't even mentioned what package you're using for your JWT. I'm just assuming `tymon/jwt-auth`. You need to provide more information.

Comment: @swonder Correct i was using same package with tymon/jwt-auth.
Please check below link i was tried to do react-laravel
https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85